# SQL Server 2008 - Change permissions to database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

We've got a database that was imported from another domain and when importing the `bak` file, the group from their domain was imported as well. And now I need to change this to the group that we have in our own domain. While preserving the permissions that are set.

I can see this when I right click the database and go to Properties and select Permissions. It says `domain\groupname` and I need to change this to `ourdomain\groupname` instead, while preserving the permissions that are set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transfer permissions from one domain to another in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335345/transfer-permissions-from-one-domain-to-another-in-sql-server)

Comment: On a second thought, not such a duplicate. Sorry, ignore me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @principal_id SMALLINT , @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

SELECT @principal_id = principal_id FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'domain\groupnameOLD'

SELECT @sql  = @sql + state_desc+N' '+permission_name+N' ON ['+s.name+N'].['+o.name+N'] TO [domain\groupnameNEW];'+Nchar(13)+NCHAR(10)
FROM sys.database_permissions p
JOIN sys.objects o
    ON p.major_id = o.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas s
    ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    class = 1
AND grantee_principal_id = @principal_id
AND minor_id = 0
AND major_id > 0

PRINT @sql
```

you know what to do after

Comment: Fantastic! I bet this will be a great resource for other in the same situation :) +1!